# tomar ultimo id insertado y enviarlo a js

Tags: php, mysql, poo, mvc, pdo

estoy aprendiendo a programar y tengo una duda de como puedo usar una variable. Como veran en el codigo, puedo tomar el ultimo id insertado y comprobe que funciona usando un 'echo'. Ahora necesito capturar esa variable con el js para poder insertarla en una tabla intermedia que tiene ids y no se muy bien como sacarla fuera del método.

```
<?php
include_once('conexion.php');
include_once('validar.php');

class Proyecto{
    protected $idproyecto;
    protected $nombre;

    public function registrarProyecto(){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO proyectos (nombre) VALUES (?)";
        $conexion = Conexion::conectar();
        $resultado=$conexion->prepare($sql);
        $resultado->bindParam(1, $this->nombre);
        $resultado->execute([$this->nombre]);
        $LAST_ID = $conexion->lastInsertId();
    }   
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

entiendo lo que buscas, para empezar te quiero decir esto, la manera más sencilla de hacer aquello sería utilizar AJAX para obtener los datos. Osea, no ejecutes dicha consulta mediante PHP y pases el resultado como variable a Js, sino con JavaScript (AJAX) haz la consulta con el método POST. Para saber más sobre este funcionamiento lee el siguiente enlace y sugiero que lo pruebes primero a modo de práctica por si es nuevo para ti.

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

PHP procesa "scripts" del lado del servidor, por otra parte JavaScript está para el lado del cliente, ambos están separados por completo y se procesan en un sistema en diversos momentos por lo que lo ideal sería aplicar lo antes mencionado.

```
$.post( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
$( ".result" ).html( data );
});
```